# Forecasting with sktime prophet

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, facebook-prophet, sktime

I am using the timeseries forecast algorithm ´prophet` from [sktime](https://sktime-backup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference/auto_generated/sktime.forecasting.fbprophet.Prophet.html).
I have the following train and test set:

```
X1_train
             Saldo
timepoint          
2017-01-01 -3574.22
2017-02-01  6351.78
2017-03-01  3297.65
2017-04-01  1016.30
...

X1_test
           Saldo
timepoint          
2017-01-01 -3574.22
...
2018-11-01  1254.95
2018-12-01  1990.26
2019-01-01  1658.30
2019-02-01   975.19
```

where both are a <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> and `Saldo: float64`and timepoint is a `datetime.index`:

```
print(X1_test.index)
         '2018-05-01', '2018-06-01', '2018-07-01', '2018-08-01',
               '2018-09-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-11-01', '2018-12-01',
               '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='timepoint', freq=None)
```

I am to train the model:

```
ph = Prophet()
ph.fit(X1_train)
```

when I try to run the forecast:

```
forecast = ph.predict(fh= [pd.date_range(X1_test.index[0], X1_test.index.max())])
```

I get the error:

> the type of the passed `fh` values is not supported..please use one of ('int', '1D np.ndarray of type int', '1D np.ndarray of type timedelta or dateoffset', 'list', 'pd.RangeIndex', 'pd.PeriodIndex', 'pd.DatetimeIndex', 'pd.TimedeltaIndex'), but found type <class 'list'>

However:

```
print(X1_test.index[0])
2017-01-01 00:00:00
```

What I am doing wrong here?